Dimension of some subspace of real polynomials of degree $\leq n$
I am now a little confused about the Question 14 from section 1.10 in Calculus Volume II by Tom Apostol, which states that

Let $P_{n}$ denote the linear space of all real polynomials of degree $\leq n$, where $n$ is fixed, let $S$ denote the set of all polynomials $f$ in $P_{n}$ satisfying the following differential equation $$f(0)+f'(0) = 0$$ Determine whether $S$ is a subspace of $P_{n}$ and the dimension of $S$ if it is a subspace.

I've proved that this $S$ is indeed a subspace and try to determine its dimension, if we solved the differential equation above, it implies that $c_{1}+c_{0} = 0$ if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k\leq n$ of the form $f = \sum_{i=0}^{k}c_{i}x^{i}$. Now I have two potential answers, and I hope someone can help me figure out which one is correct.
The first answer is $n+1$. This is because we need the basis ${1,x,x^{2},\cdots,x^{n}}$ to span this subspace. For instance, $x-1$ is a solution to the DE above and we need the linear combination of $1$ and $x$ to form this solution.
The second answer is $n$. The reason for this is that after we solved the DE above, it imposes a restriction on $c_{0}$ and $c_{1}$. More specifically, now we only need $n$ coefficients to determine a certain solution.
Now I think the first one is correct, because it fits the definition of a basis. For the second answer, I think it already implicitly assumed the $n+1$ basis and confused the definition of dimension and degree of freedom, but I am not very sure about this.

Since $c_0$ now determines $c_1$ the dimension is $n$ (the other coefficients are free to roam).
In other words,  we have all polynomials of the form: $$c_nx^n+\dots +c_2x^2+c_1x-c_1.$$
A basis is $$\{x-1,x^2,\dots x^n\}.$$

You can tell the dimension isn't $n+1,$ because that would be the whole space, and not all polynomials work.

If the first idea worked, then you would be able to find and explicitly describe the basis for $S$ (rather than handwave about it "fitting the definition of a basis"), and I would challenge you to do so rather than going on a gut feeling.
Perhaps we could invalidate it a different way: we should certainly know that $\dim P_n = n+1$. So this begs a question: why should $S$ - a set formed from $P_n$, but with additional constraints! - have the same dimension as $P_n$? That would, in fact, imply $S = P_n$, which I hope would strike you as silly, and you'd be able to find plenty of counterexamples.
On the other hand, for your second approach, if you had $p(x) = \sum_0^n c_kx^k$ in $S$, you will have found a constraint on the values of the $c_k$, as you mentioned. How many free-to-choose values do you have? That will determine the dimension, and you can tie those free-to-choose $c_k$ to basis elements $x^k$ to establish a basis that validates the dimension.
